# drawing different shapes with geometry along a curved linestring causes issue while modifying using openlayers & turf

Tags: javascript, openlayers, turfjs

I'm working recently to draw some shapes (svg images) along a curved linestring, i managed to draw the shapes using geometry by adding the styles for each shape. And now, i need to modify this linestring feature it means i want that the shapes move also when modifying the line and later the shapes will be changed with other images (circles..).
i have created my own function modify that recreate the feature and called drawShape function but it's heavy and not working correctly.
so is there any other solution to facilitate the draw of the shapes to facilate modify function also the other tasks (edit segment: change shapes), add segment...
Thanks in advance.
Some parts of code are passed here

```
// that function map the poignees passes the id( number of segment ) to drawShapes function  
 const drawShapesAll = function(feature){
      poingees.forEach((elm, id) => {
          if(id === poingees.length -1) return;
          drawShapes(feature, id+1, elm.src); // id+1 : represent the number of segment 
      });
 } 
//drawShapes funtion: draw shapes for one segment
const drawShapes = function(feature, coordsSeg, src){
  //src : svg image that i want to add it (triangle)
  const styles = feature.getStyle();
  const index0 = getClosestPointToCoords(coords, poignees[numSeg-1]); 
  const index1 = getClosestPointToCoords(coords, poignees[numSeg]);
  const coordsSeg = [];   //coordsSeg: represent coordinates (geometry) for segment i (the curved line from  poigne i to poigne i+1)
  for(var j=index0; j<= index1; j++)  {
      coordsSeg.push(coords[j]);
    }
  const coordsTrans = coordsSeg.map((coord) => (transform(coord, "EPSG:3857", "EPSG:4326"))); // get coordinates tranformed for each segment  
  const num = turf.distance(coordsTrans[0], coordsTrans[coordsTrans.length -1]) / 200; // calculate the distance for segment i then devide it by 200 to get the number of shapes for that segment (200 represent the distance between each shape)
  let line = {
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
          },
        "geometry": { 
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": coordsTrans
          }
  };
  while(i < number ){  // a loop function that draw shapes with number equal  = num
        let {point,rotation:rotation2} = getPointInCurve(line, coordsSeg, 200 * i); // 
        let pointGeo = new Point(point); 
        styles.push(new Style({ 
          geometry: pointGeo,
          image: new Icon (({
            rotation: - rotation2,
            offset: [1, 1],
            anchor : [0.9, 0.9],
            src : src,
            scale: 0.3
          }))
      }));
        feature.setStyle(styles);
       i++; 
     }
}
// getPointInCurve : get point geometry(coordinates) and rotation along the segment
function getPointInCurve(line, coords, distance){ 
  //that function call bezier function , get the curved coordinates ,
  // i used along to get the position of each shape which has distance = 200*i
  const curved = turf.bezier(line);
  const along = turf.along(curved, distance);
  const alongCoordTrans = convertCoordinates(along.geometry.coordinates[0], along.geometry.coordinates[1]);
  const prev = coords[closestPoint(coords, alongCoordTrans).index];
  const dx =   alongCoordTrans[0] -  coords[coords.indexOf(prev) - 5][0]  ; // calculate dx and dy 
  const dy =   alongCoordTrans[1] - coords[coords.indexOf(prev)  - 5][1];
  const rotation2 = Math.atan2(dy, dx); // calculate rotation of that shape
  const min = getClosestPointToCoords(coords, alongCoordTrans);
  const closetPoint = coords[min];
  return {point:closetPoint, rotation:rotation2};  // return the point coordinates and rotation of shape i, 
}
```

[image]

Comment: The heaviest part is probably creating new Icon styles at each call.  It might be better to build a cache of styles which can be reused `style.getGeometry().setCoordinates(point); style.getImage().setRotation(-rotation2);` and only create new ones if the array needs to be extended.

Comment: yes but Most of time the linestring is extended then the number/positions of shapes(points) is changed , and for modify function i  recreate the curved feature so maybe here i'm obliged to create new shapes.

Comment: If the positions change reuse the previous styles by resetting the coordinates and rotation.  If you maintain a cache you only need to create new styles if the total needed exceeds the previous cache size.

Comment: in my case , while mooving(modifiyin) the line : the distance will augment or decrease => number of shapes change so i'm obliged to create new styles, so how can i use the cache and not sure i didn't understand well what do you mean by cache, can u just give me a small example please ?

Comment: It is easier to implement if you use style functions which return styles instead of setting them on the features https://codesandbox.io/s/draw-and-modify-features-forked-twpglr?file=/main.js

Comment: thanks so much , yes i noticed that earlier make style function is better, i tried your example in my local draw working but modify still have issue. (you can see the issue here)  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SLd-xlyaXoAFxopjzX2KiDNdKQHhJzqm/view

Comment: It looks like you are drawing new features instead of modifying,

Comment: yes  sorry , i fixed the issue  now. it's working , thanks a lot Mike , i also post an issue here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872122/edit-each-segment-of-a-curved-linestring-with-different-stroke-color-using-openl  , the same draw (with shapes)  i just need to make a different stroke color for each segment. so i keep the same logic and i use ForEachSegment inside styleFunction yes?

Comment: like this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wxRd.png ( a diffrent stroke color  & shapes) will be edited for each segment

Comment: You would need caches for each symbol type, so more indexes needed, but same principle.

Comment: yes alright for caches would be for each symbole , just for the stroke color for each segment , so i  use feature.ForEachsegment inside styleFunction .. then i make a style for each segment line it will not causes issue while modifying like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73872122/edit-each-segment-of-a-curved-linestring-with-different-stroke-color-using-openl you see the original stroke which is always moved ?