# Edit each segment of a curved linestring with different stroke color using openlayers & turf

Tags: javascript, openlayers, turfjs

I'm working with openlayers 6 ,and i have created the curved linestring and i'm supposing to Split it to segments where segment represent the curved Line from a poignee to another.
These segments have their own styles(stroke and some shapes..(will be added later like styles).
As you see below i used **ForEachSegment** function that Map the feature  segments then i calculate the geometry of each segment and i passed it  to a new style.  the issue i lost control to my original linestring when i used modify ineteraction of openlayers Always it moves the previous linestring (the black one).

```
          **1- function draw :**

  const drawFront = new Draw({ 
source: srcLayer.getSource(),
type: 'LineString',
style: function (feature) {
    if (feature.getGeometry().getType() === 'LineString') {
        feature.setStyle([
            new Style({
                stroke: new Stroke({
                    color: '#000000',
                    width: 2,
                }),
                geometry: (feature) => {
                    let geometry = createCurvedLine(
                        feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates()
                    );
                    
                    return geometry
                },
            }),
            
        ]);
    }
},
```

});

**2 -function that create the curvedline :**

```
   const createCurvedLine = (coordinates) => {
  if (!map) return;
   let geometry = new LineString([]);
   geometry.set('frontCoordinates', coordinates)
    let line = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": coordinates
        }
      };
      const curved =turf.bezier(line);
      geometry.setCoordinates(curved["geometry"]["coordinates"]);
      return geometry;
  };
```

drawEnd function : the part that add for each segment it's own style ( actually it is supposed that the user will select a color from a window options the that color will be affected to the selected segment but just to simplify  things i passed colors like constant )

```
function drawEnd(e){
    const feature = e.feature;
    setDrawing(false);
    const poignees = feature.getGeometry().get('frontCoordinates');
    const styles = feature.getStyle();
    feature.setStyle(styles);
    setDrawing(false);
    setSelectedFeature(feature);
    let colors = ['red','green','blue']; // some colors : 
   feature.getGeometry().forEachSegment(function (start, end) {
    console.log("start", start, "end",end);
      const coords = feature.getStyle()[0].getGeometry()(feature).getCoordinates();
      const index0 = getClosestPointToCoords(coords, start);
      const index1 = getClosestPointToCoords(coords, end);
      const coordsP0P1 = [];
       for(var j=index0; j<= index1; j++)  {
             coordsP0P1.push(coords[j]);
        }
       let geometry = new LineString([]);
       let line = {
         "type": "Feature",
         "properties": {
           },
         "geometry": {
           "type": "LineString",
           "coordinates": coordsP0P1
           }
         };
         const curved =turf.bezier(line);
         geometry.setCoordinates(curved["geometry"]["coordinates"]);
        const style = new Style({
          stroke: new Stroke({
            color: colors[i],
            width: 2,
        }),
          geometry: geometry    
        })
          console.log("style is ", style);
         styles.push(style);
        i++;
    })
    feature.setStyle(styles);
}
```

**Modify ineteraction:**

```
const modify_front = new Modify({
  source: vectorLayer.getSource(),
  insertVertexCondition: shiftKeyOnly,
  removePoint: altKeyOnly,
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your problem is  you never update the geometry of the feature you're modifying.  The geometry property of a Style object is only apply at rendering time, it doesn't affect the original feature you modify using modify Interaction.  On draw end you should do a feature.setGeometry somewhere, you shoudn't set a new style.